# SQL Server Event Log Summary

Tags: sql-server, logs, alerts, event

I want to generate a daily summary of SQL Server Event Logs which will be sent via email. I have currently been able to set up SQL email alerts for error logs,but they are sent individualy when an error occur. What i want to achieve it a daily summary report of all SQL Server logs which will be sent directly to an email. This way without going to sql server logs on SSMS, i will see all server logs recorded for a particular day.

Comment: What is wrong with this question?

Comment: Define "summary". You can use sp_readerrorlog to input the stuff into a table and then do a SELECT from that table to include only todays events and include that in the email (using a query to sp_send_dbmail). But if you want to *refine* the info, and only get the non-noise events, then we need to know how you define which events that you want to exclude.

Comment: @kakaz it is not well-defined (and as such, closed as unclear what the OP is asking). Can you write a query that e-mails the exact daily summary the OP wants? I certainly can't. The OP needs to explain exactly what they mean, edit the question to include that much more specific info, and then it can be considered for re-opening. If they just want the full contents of yesterday's error log mailed to someone today, they need to visit tutorials for Database Mail and/or SQL Server Agent. If they have problems accomplishing that, they need to show what they tried and explain their specific problems

Comment: @kakaz I would have closed it for the same reason, but five of your peers reached that consensus first.

Comment: https://github.com/scsimon/sqlserver/blob/master/usp_error_log

Comment: Usually non noise events are those which has any importance for ordinary administrator without using debug mode. Saying that, I must admit, you are completely right: there is nearly no such informations in Microsoft technologies, and there's no possible to construct useful information from Microsoft error logs... Sad, but true

Answer (score 1):

**If you are looking to track specific severity errors or specific events, you could use alerts**

[Microsoft Docs on Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/alerts?view=sql-server-2017)

> Events are generated by SQL Server and entered into the Microsoft
>   Windows application log. SQL Server Agent reads the application log
>   and compares events written there to alerts that you have defined.
>   When SQL Server Agent finds a match, it fires an alert, which is an
>   automated response to an event. In addition to monitoring SQL Server
>   events, SQL Server Agent can also monitor performance conditions and
>   Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) events.

You can read up on configuring all of this [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3384/configuring-critical-sql-server-alerts/)

**The steps in a nutshell**

- Configure sql server database mail
- Add alerts for the events you want to track

*An example of adding an alert for `severity 17`*

```
USE [msdb]
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=N'Error 17 Alert', 
  @message_id=0, 
  @severity=17, 
  @enabled=1, 
  @delay_between_responses=0, 
  @include_event_description_in=1;
GO
```

- Configure the operator

*An example of creating an operator `DBA`. Mails will be sent to `DBA@mycompany.com`*

```
USE msdb;
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_operator
  @name = 'DBA',
  @enabled = 1,
  @email_address = 'DBAs@mycompany.com';
GO
```

- Configure the alert to be mapped to the operator

*The `@notification_method = 1` means `E-mail`*

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_notification 
  @alert_name = N'Error 17 Alert',
  @operator_name = 'DBAs',
  @notification_method = 1;
GO
```

Repeat the second and fourth step for additional alerts.

---

If you want to create your own reports, you could cook something up with the `sys.xp_readerrorlog` function and add your own filtering. What you want to keep or discard depends on your requirements.

More on reading the error log with `xp_readerrorlog` [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1476/reading-the-sql-server-log-files-using-tsql/)